# Want to use if statement with running select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

when using doing an insert statement with a sql statment
do the following

```
Insert tablename (column1, column2)
select statement
```

Is there a way to format an if statement so that if a varible is set you would run the insert statement.  This is what I have but it shows the end statement in error so i need help

```
if @runthis=1 

begin
insert tablename (column1, column2)
end
select column1, column2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use BEGIN after the IF, you must also include an END after the INSERT, and NOT in the middle of the INSERT..SELECT.

Like this:

```
if @runthis=1 

begin 
insert tablename (column1, column2) select column1, column2
end
```

Technically, you could avoid using an ELSE as you describe in your comment by using dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = '';

if @runthis=1 

begin 
SET @SQL = 'insert tablename (column1, column2) ';
end

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'select column1, column2';

EXECUTE (@SQL);
```

Personally, I would use an `ELSE` instead though.

Comment: my goal is to not have to have an else but to be able to run the select statement if runthis is not 1 and if it is 1 run it as part of the insert

Comment: That is not possible without an `ELSE`.   Well, you could avoid ELSE by using dynamic sql, but I wouldn't advise it.   Using an ELSE will perform faster.

Comment: so if I have a sql statement that has a literal in it such as the following. how would i deal with the string termination

Comment: so if I have a sql statement that has a literal in it such as the following. how would i deal with the string termination @sql='Select provider_id, null, '1', null)'

Comment: Double the single quotes around the string literal.

Answer (score 2):

The statements used inside a `IF` condition should be valid. The correct way to use `IF` condition is pointed out in other answer.

Here is another way

```
insert tablename (column1, column2) 
select column1, column2
Where @runthis=1
```

Comment: my goal is to not have to have an else but to be able to run the select statement if runthis is not 1 and if it is 1 run it as part of the insert